# Attaching JavaScript to the prototype of an ASCX client side instance

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ascx, prototype-programming

How can I code my ASCX control so that I can give an ID and from the browser run some javascript such as

```
$find('myASCXControlClientId')
```

and the returned object, has a class with a prototype with my custom javascript methods that can be called on said instance of the control?

The Telerik controls such as RadTreeView can do this for instance

[image]

The control they fetch with Javascript has a prototype with some neatly defined methods.
How can I do this with ASCX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RadControl you show above might have been implemented as a [ScriptControl](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/05/ASPNET_Create_AJAX_Server_Controls_using_the_ScriptControl_base_class.aspx) instead of a UserControl (which has the extra .ascx file).

You might already know that the ScriptControl class does exactly what you are asking and when  you do `$find(elementid)` it returns the actual javascript object of the control.

The problem that I hate with the ScriptControl is that you basically have to build your control's DOM elements programmatically by adding .NET objects like `Table` and `Label` to your control's `ChildControls` collection during `Load` or `PreRender`

One of the options that I have seen work is to create a ScriptControl that houses your properties and methods, and then wrap that with an ascx UserControl:

ScriptControl Example:

```
public class MyScriptControl : System.Web.UI.ScriptControl
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }

    protected override IEnumerable<ScriptDescriptor> GetScriptDescriptors()
    {
        //your implementations
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<ScriptReference> GetScriptReferences()
    {
        //your implementations
    }
}
```

UserControl Example:

```
public partial class MyUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{        
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        this.MyLabel.Text = this.MySpecialScriptControl.MyProperty;

        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
}
```

.ascx Example:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Example.ascx.cs" Inherits="Example" %>

<div>
    <asp:Label id="MyLabel" runat="server" />
    <my:MyScriptControl id="MySpecialScriptControl" runat="server" />
</div>
```

This should allow you to get both control over your ascx markup and the ability in javascript to do something like:

```
var myScriptControl = $find('MySpecialScriptControl');
```